# How to find the number of times a group of a specific value is present in an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have a 1 by 1000 (1 row by 1000 columns) matrix that contain only 0 and 1 as their elements. How can I find how many times 1 is repeated 3 times consecutively.

If there are more than 3 ones then it is necessary to reset the counting. So 4 would be 3+1 and it counts as only one instance of 3 consecutive 1s but 6 would be 3+3 so it counts as two instances of having 3 consecutive 1s.

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviour you want if there's 4 1s in a row for example? Should that add one or two to the total? What about if there's 6 1s in a row?

Comment: Not sure how this got three upvotes to be honest. @thinkingdude When asking a question, you are supposed to show your attempt.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Although the question does not contain code, its easy to understand and the problem is reproducable.And unlike 90% of the other questions under this tag, the question is an interesting puzzle to solve, which does not occur that often. So although it does not reach a high standard, its still way better than most of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach finds the differences between when A goes from 0 to 1 (rising edge) and from 1 to 0 (falling edge). This gives the lengths of consecutive 1s in each block. Then divide these numbers by 3 and round down to get the number of runs of 3.

Padding `A` with a 0 at the start and end just ensures we have a rising edge at the start if A starts with a 1, and we have a falling edge at the end if A ends with a 1.

```matlab
A = round(rand(1,1000));

% padding with a 0 at the start and end will make this simpler
B = [0,A,0];
rising_edges = ~B(1:end-1) & B(2:end);
falling_edges = B(1:end-1) & ~B(2:end);
lengths_of_ones = find(falling_edges) - find(rising_edges);

N = sum(floor(lengths_of_ones  / 3));
```

Or in a much less readable 2 lines:

```matlab
A = round(rand(1,1000));

B = [0,A,0];
N = sum(floor((find(B(1:end-1) & ~B(2:end)) - find(~B(1:end-1) & B(2:end)))  / 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom functions like below

```
v = randi([0,1],1,1000);

% get runs in cell array
function C = runs(v)
  C{1} = v(1);
  for k = 2:length(v)
    if v(k) == C{end}(end)
      C{end} = [C{end},v(k)];
    else
      C{end+1} = v(k);
    end
  end
end 

% count times of 3 consecutive 1s 
function y = count(x)
  if all(x)
    y = floor(length(x)/3);
  else
    y = 0;
  end
end

sum(cellfun(@count,runs(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another vectorized way:

```
% input
n = 3;
a = [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
%        x           x           x           x     x      = 5

% output
a0 = [a 0];
b = cumsum( a0 )                         % cumsum
c = diff( [0 b( ~( diff(a0) + 1 ) ) ] )  % number of ones within group
countsOf3 = sum( floor( c/n ) )          % groups of 3
```

You like it messy? Here is a one-liner:

```
countsOf3 = sum(floor(diff([0 getfield(cumsum([a 0]),{~(diff([a 0])+1)})])/n))
```